# javascript promise executes code synchronously despite of promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so basically i have a web application that retrieves data from firebase. Since it takes time to query, i used promises in javascript so that my code will execute at the right time. In function getDataFirebase, data is retrieved from firebase and is push to an array called Collect. So, after pushing 1 row, it query again to the firebase for another table of data to be collected then continues the loop. So, i create a promise before calling Firebase, and then resolving afterwards. But, im not doing that on getDataUsers.once("value"). There, i'm firing event and not waiting for it to return - the for-loop continues on, and all the callbacks processed later, but resolve is at the end of the for-loop, so its too late by then.

I used the async keyword in the when querying hoping that it would cause the for0loop to wait for that job to complete, but actually all it does here is causing the callback to return a promise - which is ingored by the on function. Its been a while already debugging and hoping that it would populate the execution at the right time. Someone pleasee help me? :(((

```
var promise = getDataFirebase();
promise.then(function () {
console.log(Collect);

console.log("firsst");
return getDataFirebaseUser();
 }).then(function () {

console.log("Second");

  });



function getDataFirebase() {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    refReview.on("value", function (snap) {
        var data = snap.val();
        for (var key in data) {


            Collect.push({
                "RevieweeName": data[key].revieweeID.firstname.concat(" ", data[key].revieweeID.lastname),
                "ReviewerName": data[key].reviewerID.firstname.concat(" ", data[key].reviewerID.lastname),
                rating: data[key].rating,
                content: data[key].content,
                keyOfReviewee: data[key].revieweeID.userID
            })
            var getDataToUsers = firebase.database().ref("users").child(data[key].revieweeID.userID);
            getDataToUsers.once("value", async function (snap) {
                var fnLn = snap.val();
                var first = fnLn.isTerminated;
                console.log("terminateStatus", first);

            });


        }//end of for loop
        resolve();
    }); //end of snap 
});
}
```

Output of console according to the code is as follows:

```
  Collect(array)
  first
  Second
  terminateStatus, 1
```

it must be

```
  Collect(array)
  first
  terminateStatus, 1
  second
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you misunderstood the concepts of async/await in javascript. Please, read this [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) from mozilla and some examples to understand how to use it.

Coming back to your problem, adding "async" keyword to the callback function in your example does not change anything. Firebase will call that function when it fetches data the same way if its async or not. And before it fetches data, you call `resolve` at the end of for loop, completing promise. So the promise is resolved before you fetch the data, which is why you get `terminateStatus` at the end.

You could use Promise returned from `once` method, and await it so that it wont go out of for loop, until all the data fetched. To do that, you have add `async` to first callback. See this:

```
function getDataFirebase() {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
refReview.on("value", async function (snap) {
    var data = snap.val();
    for (var key in data) {
        Collect.push({
            "RevieweeName": data[key].revieweeID.firstname.concat(" ", data[key].revieweeID.lastname),
            "ReviewerName": data[key].reviewerID.firstname.concat(" ", data[key].reviewerID.lastname),
            rating: data[key].rating,
            content: data[key].content,
            keyOfReviewee: data[key].revieweeID.userID
        })
        var getDataToUsers = firebase.database().ref("users").child(data[key].revieweeID.userID);
        var snapshot = await getDataToUsers.once("value");
        var fnLn = snapshot.val();
        var first = fnLn.isTerminated;
        console.log("terminateStatus", first);

    }//end of for loop
    resolve();
}); //end of snap 
});
}
```

However, this is still not very good piece of code since you call `refReview.on` method each time inside a different promise. You should either call it once in your app and attach a callback, or you should use `refReview.once` method if you just intend to fetch one document for each call.

Comment: it works. thank you very much abeyaz. ill take your advice and improve the code.